# Fluid Viewhelper f:format.json returns htmlentities and more problems with curly braces in fluid

Tags: typo3

in TYPO3 8 LTS i try build a json output from news list. When using the viewhelper f:format.json in exact the same way as in the fluid manual:

```
{f:format.json(value: {foo: 'bar', bar: 'baz'})}
```

i get this:

```
{&quot;foo&quot;:&quot;bar&quot;,&quot;bar&quot;:&quot;baz&quot;}
```

this works:

```
{f:format.json(value: newsItem.datetime)->f:format.htmlentitiesDecode()}
```

but i need the date-object formatted in this way:

```
{newsItem.datetime->f:format.date(format: "%Y-%m-%d")}
```

and now i am looking for a possibility to match both in order to get this output:

```
{'date':'2018-03-16'}
```

I tried a many ways like this, but nothing works.

```
{f:format.json(value: {date:newsItem.datetime->f:format.date(format: "%Y-%m-%d")})->f:format.htmlentitiesDecode()}
```

any idea how to get it right?
Thanks
Peter

Comment: have you tried `f:format.raw` instead of `f:format.htmlentitiesDecode`? have you tried `{date:'{newsItem.datetime->f:format.date(format: "%Y-%m-%d")}'}` ?

Comment: Very good Bernd!! Both is working.And if i am trying very hard i am able to understand why :-) Thanks!. I will write it in an answer, so everybody can see it solved.

Comment: `format.raw`is the viewhelper for unchanged output (I wonder why it is removed in the documentation of v8). you need it as since v8 the output of viewhelpers is by default `htmlentitiesencode`d. the second might neccessary as you start with an object and want a string. doing a variable evaluation (wrapping in `'{ }'`) makes sure it is a string.

Comment: I wonder why this htmlencoding was introduced, any clues?

Comment: security i presum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well Bernd showed me the way in his comment above - here is one of the solutions which i found with this little help of him:

```
{f:format.json(value: {date:'{newsItem.datetime->f:format.date(format: "%Y-%m-%d")}'})->f:format.htmlentitiesDecode()}
```

f:format.raw works much the same like f:format.htmlentitiesDecode; really important are the two '' around {newsItem.datetime->f:format.date(format: "%Y-%m-%d")}.

With the idea of format.raw i found an other solution too:

```
<f:format.raw value='{"date":"' />{newsItem.datetime->f:format.date(format: "%Y-%m-%d")}<f:format.raw value='"},' />
```

Looks quite a bit complicated but with

```
<f:format.raw value='{' />
<f:format.raw value='}' />
```

it is possible to use curly brackets in fluid templates.

Thanks!